# Is there a simple way for a script to detect what nvidia drivers a user needs?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I am trying to make a script for my friends to install a bunch of programs, the same way you would with the terminal. However, they all have different types of nVidia graphics cards, a few of them with different drivers. Is there a ***SIMPLE*** way to detect the newest compatible driver? Or do they need to figure out what driver they need themselves and edit it manually.